# Java : Did i do something wrong when i added this panel?

Tags: java, swing

I was in the middle creating pong and I wasn't sure if I did something wrong or anything. If the error has nothing to do with the frame please tell me.

```
public class PongFrame extends JFrame {
  PongFrame(){
    super("PONG");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(600,400);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setLocation(450,200);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    PongPanel panel = new PongPanel();

    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  }
}
```

Comment: You just set the `JFrame.setVisible( ... )` property to `true`, much before you have added any component to it. Make it the last line, and call it, only when all components have been added to the same :-)

Comment: What **is** the error?

Comment: A lot can go wrong in Swing GUIs, and this needs more context. At least tell us what "the error" is, what you were expecting to happen, and where you're calling this code from.

Comment: thanks for the help I'l change my error right away.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `this.setVisible(true);` before you've completed constructing the GUI, you should, where possible, call this last

```
public class PongFrame extends JFrame {
    PongFrame(){
        super("PONG");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        PongPanel panel = new PongPanel();

        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setSize(600,400);
        this.setLocation(450,200);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

You should also rely on `JFrame#pack` instead of `setSize`